# Passing parameter to hbm2ddl

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ant, hbm2ddl

I have parametrized persistence.xml. I am trying to generate ddl schema using hbm2ddl. How can i pass parameters to this tool ?

My persistence.xml looks like

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${persistence.connection.driver.class}"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${persistence.dialect}"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${persistence.password}"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${persistence.username}"/>
```

When i start server parameter values are passed as JAVA_OPTS (using -Dpersistence.dialect=value). And it works well.

How do i do this with hbm2ddl ?

I tried property

```
<hibernatetool destdir="${gensrc.sql.dir}">
  <property key="persistence.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect"/>
  <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="${persistence.unit.name}" />
  <classpath>
   <!-- it is in this classpath you put your classes dir,
       and/or jpa persistence compliant jar -->
    <path location="${build.classes.dir}" />
  </classpath>
  <hbm2ddl export="false" drop="true" outputfilename="create_${ant.project.name}.sql" format="true" haltonerror="true" />
</hibernatetool>
```

But it does not get this value. It shows me error.

```
build.xml:160: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: ${persistence.dialect}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the dialect via `propertyfile`. Declare it in  a `hibernate.properties`:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
```

And use it like this:

```
<jpaconfiguration propertyfile="hibernate.properties"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I was referring to https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html/ant.html

How can i do this using ant ? I mean can you point me where i should specify these properties in my <hibernatetools> on <hbm2ddl>

Thanks.

Comment: @Jigar Sorry, wrong link. I've updated my anwser with others suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again. It worked. (first one). (jpaconfiguration does not support prop attribute. )

Small issues still remains. Purpose of making persistence.xml parameterised was to change this value at run time. So if want to generate ddl for oracle, i can just specify a param with dialect and it generates ddl. Here i have to specify a file with hibernate.dialect=oracle.driver. I have done that for now and it works. Thanks for your reply.